# Blank Screen After submitting form for Importing xls to mysql

Tags: php, excel

This is code for importing its just showing a blank page after submitting a form with .xls file I dunno wats wrong in it my code please help me.
My database config file has  no error in it , coz it is working fine with xls import from my sql.

Iam using linux server

HTML:

```
    <form action="importData.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="importFrm1">
        <input type="file" name="file" style="margin-top: 30px;px;" /><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="importSubmit" name="importSubmit" value="IMPORT" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    </form>
```

This is my php code:importData.php

```
 <?php  session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header("Location:sessionerror.php");
exit;
 }
include "connection2.php";

//load the database configuration file
if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){
// Validate whether uploaded file is a csv file
$csvMimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/csv');
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

        //open uploaded csv file with read only mode
        $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
        //skip first line
        fgetcsv($csvFile);
        // Parse data from csv file line by line
    while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile,1000, "\t")) !== FALSE){

      $ID=$line[0];
      $projectName=$line[1];
      $projectLocation=$line[2];
      $builderName=$line[3];
      $builderGrade=$line[4];
      $wheatherOCReceived=$line[5];
      $startingPriceRs=$line[6];
      $size_SBA=$line[7];
      $configuration=$line[8];
      $discount=$line[9];
      $segment=$line[10];
      $amenities=$line[11];
      $filenme=$line[12];
      $DateModified=$line[13];

            //check whether member already exists in database with same email
            $prevQuery = "SELECT id FROM info WHERE id = '".$line[0]."'";
            $prevResult = $conn->query($prevQuery);
            if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){
                //update member data
                $conn->query("UPDATE `featured_projects`.`info`
                 SET `projectName`='$projectName',`projectLocation`='$projectLocation',`builderName`='$builderName',`builderGrade`='$builderGrade',`wheatherOCReceived`='$wheatherOCReceived',`startingPriceRs`='$startingPriceRs',`size_SBA`='$size_SBA',`configuration`='$configuration',`discount`='$discount',`segment`='$segment',`amenities`='$amenities',`featuredImage`='$target_file',`date`='$DateModified'
                    WHERE `id` = '".$ID."'") or die("Unable to update: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }else{
                //insert member data into database
                $conn->query("INSERT INTO `featured_projects`.`info` (`id`, `projectName`, `projectLocation`, `builderName`, `builderGrade`, `wheatherOCReceived`, `startingPriceRs`, `size_SBA`, `configuration`, `discount`, `segment`, `amenities`, `featuredImage`, `date`)
                 VALUES ('$ID', '$projectName', '$projectLocation', '$builderName', '$builderGrade', '$wheatherOCReceived', '$startingPriceRs', '$size_SBA', '$configuration', '$discount', '$segment', '$amenities', '$filenme', '$DateModified')" or die("Unable to  Insert: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
        }
        //close opened csv file
        fclose($csvFile);
        $qstring = '?status=succ';
    }else{
        $qstring = '?status=err';
    }
   }else{
     $qstring = '?status=invalid_file';
   }
  }
   //redirect to the listing page
   header("Location: admin-ready-home-in-bangalore2.php".$qstring);?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: On your `INSERT` query, you're missing a closing parenthesis before the `or`.

Comment: Thankyou Now its working